# Use pymc3 variable to set the length of another variable?

Tags: theano, pymc3

Is it possible to use a pymc3 RV to set the shape of another RV?

I'm looking to do something along the lines of:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
        n_obj = pm.Poisson(name='n', mu=5)
        objs = pm.Uniform(lower=0, upper=1, shape=(n_obj, 2))
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'TensorVariable' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, roughly because this would imply your model changing dimension while sampling (which kinda sorta changes the model).

Luckily, you can usually fake a model like this: set the shape of `objs` to more than the maximum number you expect, and then you can slice `objs[:n_obj, :]` and use it downstream.

[This](https://austinrochford.com/posts/2016-02-25-density-estimation-dpm.html) is a good writeup from Austin Rochford using this approach for Dirichlet processes.

Comment: That writeup is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you!